# Can I solder 5V USB to a tablet battery connector?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, usb

Dad asked me to solder a cable to the broken microUSB connector, but it's totally broken and it's really hard to solder it that way, so I want to solder a cable directly to the battery connector and completely remove the battery from the tablet since the battery won't be in use. Will the circuit take those 5V from the USB or should I find like a 4V power supply?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it cannot be answered without consulting the data sheet of the PMIC used by the tablet

Comment: Try tracing the tracks on the PCB which run to the destroyed USB connector and see if you can find another convenient pad or through-hole to solder the wire(s) to.

Answer (score 2):

In the past while debugging power management on portable SOCs, I have removed the lithium ion battery, connected a power supply with logging capability, and then connected the battery thermistor so that the PMIC still thinks the battery is present.  You do need to provide the correct voltage, or else the PMIC may think the battery is catastrophically over voltage and turn off.  Without knowledge of your specific device, I cannot tell you definitively if this will work for you, but it is plausible.

It may still be better to use the USB connector however.  You can ignore the data pins, so it is often very simple to desolder the existing broken connector, and then find somewhere under it where the +5 and GND traces are accessible even if the traces have lifted off the board.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. You need a charger and safety circuit between whatever voltage supply you use (no matter whether it's 5V from USB or 4V from somewhere else) and your battery.

Your tablet has a lithium battery.  You can't charge a Lithium Battery with constant voltage; [it will catch fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuKF8XfCVKQ&feature=emb_logo).

Hence, you need the charger integrated in your tablet, or another Lithium battery charging circuit that matches the properties of that battery.

Conclusion: Replace the microUSB connector.

Comment: No I meant that i will completely remove the battery from the tablet since he doesnt need it there, ive wanted to connect the power supply into the battery connector instead of the battery

Comment: that probably won't work either, since the charger will detect it's not a functioning battery and refuse to use it, because: malfunctioning Lithium batteries being used catch fire.

Comment: @Marcus Müller If it's a simple power supply or a USB supply, it will deliver current no matter what. But maybe the tablet won't recognize this current as coming from a battery and will refuse to turn on. In a simple worrld, connecting the same  voltage as the battery should work. But it's not a simple world.

Comment: @Fredled exactly what I meant to say.